# Selenide drvier, Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Tags: gradle, selenium-chromedriver, selenide

I read most of threads about this problem, but can't find solution. I used selenide 4.11.1, but i have problem "This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74" after running tests. So according to this solution https://twitter.com/jselenide/status/1105734134633127938 I upgrade in my build.gradle file version of selenide to: testCompile 'com.codeborne:selenide:5.2.1'. And now i get following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'cc', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-46-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: SelenideDriver
selenide.url: http://test.local
selenide.baseUrl: http://test.local
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:573)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
```

I checked my etc/hosts file and it seems to be ok:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   cc
127.0.0.1   test.local
```

Maybe I miss something and updating selenide via gradle should be done with more than one step?
edit. Problem is that chrome is not opening

I always enable test via ./gradlew:

```
./gradlew \
  -Dselenide.baseUrl=http://test.local:82 \
  -Dselenide.browser=chrome \
  -Dselenide.remote=http://localhost:4444/wd/hub \
  -Dselenide.timeout=4000 \
  test --tests Tests.Test2.test3
```

Comment: i am also facing this issue with {selenium/chrome webdriver} since yesterday. this is caused due to latest chromedriver upgrade. found this link. you may get some help - https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/313

Comment: I update to selenide 5.2.1 and remove Dselenide remote for now.. and works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update to selenide 5.2.1 and remove Dselenide remote for now.. and works :)